# Rails: What makes every css file linked to all .erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have notice that all my css files are linked to the erb view files. Does it have anything to do with asset pipeline or prockets rails?

I would like to know how I would be able to disable the feature and make it so that only certain css files are linked to specific erb files.

Here is the github link to the project: https://github.com/PabiGamito/pandora

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "erb files"?  Do you mean views?

Comment: Are you referring to all your css files being chained inside `application.css`? And this, then, being linked in all HTML pages?

Comment: Yes to the first comment and @tompave yes, I think that is what might be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "views" when you say "erb files," then you'll probably want to take a look at `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.  On line 5, you have this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

This is what includes the stylesheets on every page.  This creates a link tag, with the `application.css` file being the target (if you go into your assets, you should find an `application.css`).

In order to only include certain stylesheets on certain pages, you're going to have to make a set of changes.

1. First, you're going to have to add a [`content_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for) below your link tag.  This allows you to define content to add at that point in another view.  You'll probably want to add a line under the stylesheet link containing this:

   ```
   <%= content_for :stylesheets if content_for?(:stylesheets) %>
   ```

   What this does is it adds the content from `:stylesheets` content if it's defined.
2. You'll have to modify your `application.css.scss` file.  On line 13, you have `require_tree .`, which requires *all* files under the `app/assets/stylesheets` directory, which is *not* what you want.  You'll have to remove it, and manually require every file you want to include with the `application.css` file.
3. You'll have to create a new file, named (for example) `admin.css(.scss)` (the `.scss` is optional).  In that file, you can place whatever styling you want.  Since you removed the `require_tree .` from the application css file, it won't be included unless you add a `require` directive for it (you don't want to do this, though).
4. In whatever view you want to have it, you have to place the following:

   ```
   <% content_for :stylesheets do %>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
   <% end %>
   ```

And that should do it.

Comment: How do I add a require directive? Would it be require "./stylesheets/admin.css"?

Comment: No, and for the context of the  question, you wouldn't want to require the `admin.css` file; however, for reference, you'd add `= require admin` as a comment.  Sprockets requires relative to the stylesheets folder, and doesn't require the extension.

Comment: Are you sure I have to remove <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>? Because when I do that the css doesn't work but when I keep it and only require the css files I need in application.css it works.

Comment: No, you don't.  You have to remove [line 13 of  your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss`](https://github.com/PabiGamito/pandora/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss#L13), because that requires all of the files in the stylesheets directory.

Comment: Yep. Thats done. Thank you very much for your help. I am new to rails so I am not sure how everything links together yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84414/discussion-between-jeremy-rodi-and-pabi).